# HTML Character Identities in Twitter

Tags: php, twitter

I'm developing a twitter app, and when I submit a new tweet from php with abrahams twitteroauth and with any special character it submits it to twitter as the HTML identity. I've tried all the html_entity_decode() and the htmlspecialchars_decode() but nothings working. Thank you :)

edit: heres some code as by request
(after logging in with oauth [which I know works] I'm doing this to submit the tweet)

`$status = $_POST['status'];
$to->post('statuses/update', array('status' => html_entity_decode(stripslashes($status))));`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your saying Kristopher

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
html_entity_decode(stripslashes($status), ENT_QUOTES)
```